# Monte Carlo Tree Search Improvements

Tags: artificial-intelligence, monte-carlo-tree-search

I'm trying to implement the MCTS algorithm on a game. I can only use around 0.33 seconds per move. In this time I can generate one or two games per child from the start state, which contains around 500 child nodes. My simulations aren't random, but of course I can't make a right choice based on 1 or 2 simulations. Further in the game the tree becomes smaller and I can my choices are based on more simulations.

So my problem is in the first few moves. Is there a way to improve the MCTS algorithm so it can simulate more games or should I use another algorithm?

Comment: what game is it? around 500 child nodes? aren't you rebuilding the tree from scratch after each move? 1 or 2 choice in child nodes might be enough, if top level nodes, the ones immediately following root, have enough childs and simulations thus."should I use another algorithm?" depends very much on the game. MCTS is bad for chess, but great for GO, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible to come up with some heuristic evaluation function for states? I realise that one of the primary benefits of MCTS is that in theory you wouldn't need this, BUT: if you can create a somewhat reasonable evaluation function anyway, this will allow you to stop simulations early, before they reach a terminal game state. Then you can back-up the evaluation of such a non-terminal game state instead of just a win or a loss. If you stop your simulations early like this, you may be able to run more simulations (because every individual simulation takes less time).

Apart from that, you'll want to try to find ways to ''generalize''. If you run one simulation, you should try to see if you can also extract some useful information from that simulation for other nodes in the tree which you didn't go through. Examples of enhancements you may want to consider in this spirit are AMAF, RAVE, Progressive History, N-Gram Selection Technique.

Do you happen to know where the bottleneck is for your performance? You could investigate this using a profiler. If most of your processing time is spent in functions related to the game (move generation, advancing from one state to the next, etc.), you know for sure that you're going to be limited in the number of simulations you can do. You should then try to implement enhancements that make each individual simulation as informative as possible. This can for example mean using really good, computationally expensive evaluation functions. If the game code itself already is very well optimized and fast, moving extra computation time into things like evaluation functions will be more harmful to your simulation count and probably pay off less.

For more on this last idea, it may be interesting to have a look through some stuff I wrote on my [MCTS-based agent in General Video Game AI](https://dennissoemers.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/09/29/the-general-video-game-agent-maastcts2.html), which is also a real-time environment with a very computationally expensive game, meaning that simulations counts are severely constrained (but the branching factor is much much smaller than it seems to be in your case). Pdf files of my publications on this are also available online.